# Sum of cubes of co-primes to a number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Similar to this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161998/is-this-proof-rigorous-and-correct-related-to-sum-of-co-primes-to-a-numbers), I am trying to find:
$$f(n)=\frac1{n^3}\sum_{\substack{a=1\\(a,n)=1}}^{n}a^3$$
Similarly I did this:
$$\begin{align}g(n)&=\sum_{d|n}f(d)\\
&=\color{gray}{\text{(see previous question)}}\\
&=\sum_{d|n}\sum_{d'|d}\mu(d')\frac{d'^3}{d^3}\sum_{m\le d/d'}m^3\\
&=\sum_{d|n}\sum_{d'|d}\mu(d')\frac{d'^3}{d^3}\left[\frac{\frac{d^2}{d'^2}\left(\frac{d}{d'}+1\right)^2}{4}\right]\\
&=\frac14\sum_{d|n}\sum_{d'|d}\left(d\frac{\mu(d')}{d'}+2\mu(d')+\frac1dd'\mu(d')\right)\\
&=\sum_{d|n}\left(\phi(d)+2\nu(d)+\frac1d\sum_{d'|d}d'\mu(d')\right)\\
&=n+2+\sum_{d|n}\frac1d\sum_{d'|d}d'\mu(d')
\end{align}$$

Now how to resolve $$\sum_{d|n}\frac1d\sum_{d'|d}d'\mu(d')$$

Comment: As $(n,a)=(n,n-a)$

$$2n^3 f(n)=\sum_{a=1,(a,n)=1}^n\{a^3+(n-a)^3\}=2\sum_{a=1,(a,n)=1}^n(n^3-3n^2a+3a^2n)$$

$$=2n^3\phi(n)-6n^2\sum_{a=1,(a,n)=1}^na+6n\sum_{a=1,(a,n)=1}^na^2$$

Now $\sum_{a=1,(a,n)=1}^na=\dfrac{n\phi(n)}2$

Answer (score 3):

Completing the comment of @lab bhattacharjee :

$$\sum_{\substack{1\le a\le n\cr(a,n)=1}}a^2=\frac{n^2}{3}\varphi(n)+\frac{n}{6}\prod_{p\mid n}(1-p)$$

I guess you can now get the whole picture :)

Comment: how do you get those two (multiplicative) terms ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{b\mid n}\frac{1}{b}\sum_{a\mid b}a\cdot\mu(a) =\sum_{a\mid n}a\cdot \mu(a)\sum_{c\mid\frac{n}{a}}\frac{1}{ac}=\sum_{a\mid n}\mu(a)\sum_{c\mid\frac{n}{a}}\frac{1}{c}$$
equals
$$ \sum_{a\mid n}\mu(a)\sum_{c\mid\frac{n}{a}}\frac{ac}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{a\mid n} a\cdot\mu(a)\cdot\sigma_1\left(\frac{n}{a}\right) $$
that is $\frac{1}{n}$ times a multiplicative function (a Dirichlet convolution). If $n=p^k$,
$$ \sum_{a\mid n} a\cdot\mu(a)\cdot\sigma_{1}\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)=\sigma_1(p^k)-p\cdot\sigma_1(p^{k-1})=1 $$
hence, simply,
$$\sum_{b\mid n}\frac{1}{b}\sum_{a\mid b}a\cdot\mu(a) = \frac{1}{n}.$$